# How to fetch data with Graphql and pass as prop into Next/Typescript component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to add a Navbar to my `nextjs`-application by using `typescript` and `graphql` but for some reason I don't know, I cannot output the menu items.

My Navbar.tsx component:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState } from "react";
import { request } from "../../lib/datocms";
import { GetStaticProps } from "next";
import NavItem from "./NavItem";

export interface INavbar {
   navActive: boolean;
   setNavActive: (value: boolean) => void;
   topNav: Object;
}

const Navbar: React.FC<INavbar> = ({ navActive, setNavActive, topNav }) => {
   const [activeIdx, setActiveIdx] = useState(-1);

   return (
    <nav className="">
      <Link href={"/"}>
        <a>My page</a>
      </Link>
      <div className={`${navActive ? "active" : ""} nav__menu-list`}>
          {topNav.menuItems.topNavigationItems.map((navitem, idx) => (
             <div onClick={() => {setActiveIdx(idx); setNavActive(false)}} key={navitem.text}>
                <NavItem active={activeIdx === idx} {...navitem} />
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    </nav>
   );
 };

 const query = `
    query {
      topNav {
         menuItems {
           topNavigationItems {
              text
              id
              path {
                slug
                title
              }
           }
        }
      }
     }
  `;

 export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
   const data = await request({
     query: query,
 });

 return {
    props: data,
  };
};

export default Navbar;
```

NavItem.tsx:

```
import Link from "next/link";

export interface INavItem {
  text: string;
  path: string;
  active: boolean;
}

const NavItem: React.FC<INavItem> = ({ text, path, active }) => {
  return (
    <Link href={path}>
       <a className={`nav__item ${active ? "active" : ""}`}>{text}</a>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default NavItem;
```

and my main Layout file, where the Navbar component is placed:

```
const MainLayout: LayoutProps = ({ children }) => {
   const [navActive, setNavActive] = useState(false);
   return (
      <div>
        <Navbar navActive={navActive} setNavActive={setNavActive} topNav={I GUESS THIS PROP MUST BE DEF HERE TOO!!??} />
        {children}
      </div>
   );
};

export default MainLayout;
```

So, can anyone tell/help me what I'm missing or doing wrong? It seems that the `graphql`-query data is not fetched correctly...

Thanks in advance

Comment: `getStaticProps` can only be used in page components, it won't run on regular components. Either call `getStaticProps` at the page level and pass the data down to the `Navbar`; or retrieve the data on the client-side inside the `Navbar` component.

Answer (score 0):

You should call graphQL into useEffect Navbar.tsx component.
Try to change like below:

```
const Navbar: React.FC<INavbar> = ({ navActive, setNavActive, topNav }) => {
   const [activeIdx, setActiveIdx] = useState(-1);
   
   useEffect(() => {
       // define query
       const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
           const data = await request({
           query: query,
           });

           return data;
       };

       getStaticProps();
   }, [])
   
...
```

Comment: I get an `'const' declarations must be initialized` error...

Comment: what is the line you got that error?

Comment: this one `}, [])`

Comment: oops, i miss a quotes :D updated!

Comment: hmm, it doesn't work - when using `useEffect` I'm having issues with my .env file - since it now can't find the data resource

Comment: basically the way to do it is to call the graphQL statement in useEffect, for other errors you can post the source code so I can better understand the problem